# Access dynamically properties of class in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

In my application, the user enters notes that appear as cards one below the other in order of insertion on the main page. When entering notes he selects a colored label. I would like each note entered to have the text highlighted in the color of the chosen label.

How can I do that?
Can I get the property Color of the class Label to use it on the containers of the main page cards?

This is the label.dart code

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 3)
class Label extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  int color;

  Label({this.name, this.color});
}

class LabelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Label> {
  @override
  final typeId = 3;

  @override
  Label read(BinaryReader reader) {
    var numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    var fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (var i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return Label(
      name: fields[0] as String,
      color: fields[1] as int,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Label obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.name)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.color);
  }
}
```

This is the code of the card in the main page:

```
  Container buildTaskCard(Task personModel) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 10, 10, 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black38,
              offset: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
              blurRadius: 2,
            ),
          ]),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 4, 0, 4.0),
            child: Text(
              personModel.name,
              style: regularBoldTxt,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 1,
            color: Colors.grey[300],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 40,
                height: 50,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      personModel.description,
                      style: regularTxt.copyWith(color: Colors.black54),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text(
                      personModel.statusTag ?? "",
                      style: regularBoldTxt,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.timer),
              const SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text(
                DateFormat("hh:ss a").format(personModel.startTime) +
                    " - " +
                    DateFormat("hh:ss a").format(personModel.endTime),
                style: regularTxt,
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the color to your method:

```
Container buildTaskCard(Task personModel, [Color color = Colors.white]) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 10, 10, 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color, //I believe you want to change this color?
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ....
    );
```

Then whenever you call this method you use the int of your label class to create your color and pass it

```
late final Widget container;
final Task task = ... //your taks;
final Label? label = box.get('myLabels') as Label?; // I dont't know where you call your box or what is its name
if (label != null) {
  final Color color = Color(label.color);
  container = buildTaskCard(mytask, color);
} else {
  container = buildTaskCard(mytask);
}
....
```

And construct your widget with it